# Using Manifest gives an error 'parameter is not recognized' from MSDeploy.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, msbuild, msdeploy

For ASP.NET project MSBuild gives some files in E:\tmp such as:

- TestProjectA.deploy.cmd
- TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml
- TestProjectA.SourceManifest.xml
- TestProjectA.zip

To deploy from Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7)

Executing command gives following error message:

**Command**

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:manifest="E:\tmp\TestProjectA.SourceManifest.xml" -dest:auto -declareParamFile="E:\tmp\TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml"
```

**Error Message**

`Error: The declared parameter 'IIS Web Application Name' is not recognized.`
`E:\tmp\TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml`
`Error count: 1.`

**TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml** file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <parameters>
     <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/TestProjectA_deploy" />
     <setParameter name="DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" value="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestProjectA-20140131141721;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestProjectA-20140131141721.mdf" />
  </parameters>
```

In IIS `TestProjectA_deploy` App exist under `Default Web Site`.

Is there any idea to solve it?

Comment: Solved by following command…… 

Configure IIS [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler)
....AND...
`C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package='E:\Test-MsDeploy\Package\TestProjectA.zip' -dest:auto,wmsvc='https://{IP}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default%20Web%20Site',user‌​Name='******',password='******',includeAcls='False' -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile="E:\Test-MsDeploy\Package\TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml" -allowUntrusted`

Comment: Answering your own question here is encouraged! Post your comment as an answer so it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Was having similar issue on the cmd line using
-setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='Default Web Site/'

Resulting in "Error: Unrecognized argument 'IIS Web Application Name=Default Web Site/'"

What I needed to do was drop the -setParam (which produced an error related to authenticaiton and contentPath) and change then change -dest:auto to -dest:contentPath='Default Web Site'